# Javascript method to remove a specific field

Tags: javascript, html

I want to attach more than one field to a div along with a remove button. Something similar to Gmail file attaching methods if the user presses the remove button it should remove the specified p along with the button. But if I press the remove button it is not working properly I know the javascript array method is the problem but I am not able to understand where I am going wrong

```
<form name="create" action ="">
  <input type="text" id="text">
  <button name="submit" onclick="attach()" type="button">Submit</button>
</form>
<div id="attach">
</div>
<script>
function attach(){
  var value =document.getElementById('text').value;
  var content = document.createElement('p'); // is a node
  content.className = 'element';
  // Insert text
  var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
  btn.innerHTML = "Delete This element";
  var i =0;

  btn.onclick = function(){
    console.log(i);
    remove(i);
    i++;
  };

  content.innerHTML = value;
  document.getElementById("attach").appendChild(content);
  document.getElementById("attach").appendChild(btn);
}

function remove(i){

  var elem = document.getElementsByClassName('element');
  elem[i].remove();
  return false;
}
</script>
```

The working plunker is here.
http://plnkr.co/edit/eYhfN85FH4XabzE4rO4M?p=preview

What is going wrong here? How can I fix this?

Comment: what's ur expected behaviour?

Comment: if the user presses the remove button it should remove the specified p along with the button.

Comment: I suspect one problem is your use of the `var i`. You'd probably have much better luck if you put the `P` and `BUTTON` tags in a common `DIV` or something, and then in your `onclick` even you can do something simpler like `this.parentElement.remove()` to remove both P and BUTTON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A slightly different approach that simplifies your original example, is to take advantage of the function/closure you create for the button you create. In there, you can literally just reference the `content` and `btn` elements, and remove them directly

```js
function attach(){
  var value =document.getElementById('text').value;
  var content = document.createElement('p'); // is a node
  content.className = 'element';
// Insert text
  var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
  btn.className = 'element';
  btn.innerHTML = "Delete This element";
  
  btn.onclick = function(){
    content.remove();
    btn.remove();
  };


  content.innerHTML = value;
  
  var attach = document.getElementById("attach");
  
  attach.appendChild(content);
  attach.appendChild(btn);
}
```

```html
<form name="create" action ="">
<input type="text" id="text">
<button name="submit" onclick="attach()" type="button">Submit</button>
</form>
<div id="attach">
</div>
```

That way, you don't have to worry about what index you're removing or anything

Answer (score 0):

Here you go!

```js
function attach() {
  const attachEl = document.getElementById("attach");
  const value = document.getElementById("text").value;
  const contentEl = document.createElement("p"); // is a node
  contentEl.className = "element";
  // Insert text
  const btnEl = document.createElement("button");
  btnEl.innerHTML = "Delete This element";
  const wrapperEl = document.createElement("div");

  btnEl.onclick = function() {
    attachEl.removeChild(wrapperEl);
  };

  attachEl.appendChild(wrapperEl);
  wrapperEl.appendChild(contentEl);
  wrapperEl.appendChild(btnEl);
  contentEl.innerHTML = value;
}
```

```css
#attach{
  background-color: teal;
}

.element {
  background-color: wheat;
}
```

```html
<form name="create" action="">
    <input type="text" id="text">
    <button name="submit" onclick="attach()" type="button">Submit</button>
</form>
<div id="attach">
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

We should use a wrapper to **wrap a p & button together** so that when we initiate delete it deletes the complete **wrapper**

```js
function attach(){
  var value =document.getElementById('text').value;
  var content = document.createElement('p'); // is a node
  var wrapper = document.createElement('div');
  wrapper.className="wrapper";
  content.className = 'element';
  // Insert text
  var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
  btn.innerHTML = "Delete This element";
  var i =0;

  btn.onclick = function(){
    console.log(i);
    remove(i);
    i++;
  };

  content.innerHTML = value;
  
  wrapper.appendChild(content);
  wrapper.appendChild(btn);
  
  document.getElementById("attach").appendChild(wrapper);
}

function remove(i){

  var elem = document.getElementsByClassName('wrapper');
  elem[i].remove();
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form name="create" action ="">
  <input type="text" id="text">
  <button name="submit" onclick="attach()" type="button">Submit</button>
</form>
<div id="attach">
</div>
```

Comment: I have tried a use case i have added an insert of 1 ,2,3 if i press the button of second the first one is getting deleted

Comment: `Remove` will always be called with 0. You'd have to move `i` to the global scope if you were to make something like this to work.